# Decode mail subject

Tags: php, email

I need to decode the subject of some mails. I have this code

```
$subject = mimie_text_decode($header->Subject);

function mimie_text_decode($string){

            $string = htmlspecialchars(chop($string));

            $elements = imap_mime_header_decode($string);

            if(is_array($elements)){
                for ($i=0; $i<count($elements); $i++) {
                    $charset = $elements[$i]->charset;
                    $txt .= $elements[$i]->text;
                }
            } else {
                $txt = $string;
            }
            if($txt == ''){
                $txt = 'No_name';
            }

            return $txt;
        }
```

When my subject is some like this `?UTF-8?Q?C=C3=BAspide?=` It works correctly, but if my subject is not UTF-8 and is like this one  `?Windows-1252?Q?Pro=F3ba?=` it does not show the characters with accents, it eliminate everything that has accents, ie only shows the words until an accent appears. If I have this word "Más" it only shows "M"

What can be the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me, but the encoded subjects you write should start by =?.

Try your code with `=?Windows-1252?Q?Pro=F3ba?=`

Windows-1252 it's another encoding created by Microsoft very similar to ISO-8859-15 [1]

If don't works for you adding this = character as the first element of the string passed to mimie_text_decode tell us which version of php are you using.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Comment: I am using PHP 5.3.10, but my server allows me to change to 5.3.2 or to 5.4.4. And you are right, I wrote my code without the =, while it starts with = and it does not work.